# query a docker mysql living in a bridge user defined network

Tags: mysql, docker, networking

With docker, I creating a network and a mysql image using:

```
 sudo docker network create --driver bridge mynet_nw
 sudo docker run --network=mynet_nw --name=mydb -v /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql:5.7
```

I want to run:

```
 mysql -uroot -pmypassword -h ????? -P 3306
```

to be able to run commands in the mydb databse. Instead of  ?????   I tried mydb but it is giving me errors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work this way. The networking options (like the --link option) are used to allow the communication among containers.

If you want to connect from the host, you can do it by using the following example:

```
MYSQL_IPADD=$( docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mydb )
mysql -uroot -pmypassword -h $MYSQL_IPADD -P 3306
```

Otherwise you can map the port 3306 to the host:

```
docker run --network=mynet_nw -p 3306:3306 --name=mydb -v /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql:5.7
mysql -uroot -pmypassword -h localhost -P 3306
```

Another option would be to use the container mysql command to communicate with the server:

```
docker run -it --network mynet_nw mysql mysql -uroot -pmypassword -h mydb -P 3306
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how you run the first one that uses MYSQL_IPADD?

Comment: actually it should be a simple copy and paste. The docker inspect will provide the info concerning the network info of the instance mydb. the result will be stored in the MYSQL_IPADD variable that you'll use later in the other command. I suggest anyway to create a script out of it

Comment: For the first one it was needed a right parenthesis  )  at the end of the  MYSQL_IPADD command and in my case I had to add the  sudo  word before docker. Thx

Comment: I am trying to avoid the link option as it has become legacy and it has been recommended to use user defined networks